`open` launches certain apps and certain files in background WITHOUT -g option
I recently started getting a strange issue on one of my Macbooks running Mac OS 14.4.1 (23E224) (but not on my other macbook). I can't figure out a pattern or debug this. Can anyone suggest what might be responsible?

iTerm2 - open -a /System/Applications/TextEdit.app ~/.zshrc - comes to foreground
iTerm2 - open -a /System/Applications/TextEdit.app ~/bin/script.sh - stays in background
iTerm2 - open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app ~/bin/script.sh - comes to foreground
iTerm2 - open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app ~/bin/script.sh - stays in background
iTerm2 - /usr/local/bin/bbedit ~/bin/script.sh - stays in background
iTerm2 - /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit  ~/.zshrc - stays in background
iTerm2 - open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/BBEdit ~/.zshrc - comes to foreground
Terminal - /usr/local/bin/bbedit ~/bin/script.sh - stays in background

Things I've checked:

I have "full disk access" in Privacy and Security for BBEdit, iTerm2 and Terminal.
which open gives me /usr/bin//open
There is no setting in iTerm2 or BBEdit that looks relevant
I've tried changing some permissions on script.sh which makes no difference.

The only pattern I can see here is that .sh files (among others, like .csv) do not come to the foreground.
Am I doing something stupid? Or is this as inexplicable to you as it is to me? It's frustrating since I open a lot of text files from the command line.

(credits: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/472744/57681)
Secure Keyboard Entry
I must have accidentally enabled Secure Keyboard Entry it in iTerm2 when trying to discover keyboard shortcuts by seeing what Cmd + Opt + S.

